# How to pass the JQuery "this" selector as a parameter

Tags: jquery

For a class, I have to make a Drag and Drop interface using only CSS, HTML 4.01, and Javascript with the JQuery library; no plugins allowed. I figure the best way to do this was aler the CSS position of the div I'm supposed to drag on mousedown and then on mouseup

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".draggable").mousedown(Dragging(this));
    function Dragging(draggableObject)
    {
        draggableObject.live("mousemove", function(){draggableObject.css(/*alters the position of the div*/)});
    };
});
```

My trouble is that draggableObject doesn't seem to have any CSS properties, I tried calling up an alert with its properties and apparently they're null. What am I doing wrong with passing the object, or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

*Why doesn't it work?* - By using `Dragging(this)` you're calling the function immediately, not running it when bound.  Also the first parameter the function gets when run as an event handler is the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

---

It should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".draggable").mousedown(Dragging);
   function Dragging() {
     $(this).bind("mousemove", function(){
       $(this).css(/*alters the position of the div*/)
     });
   }
});
```

In an event handler `this` *already* refers to the element, there's no need to pass it around.  You can also shorten it down like this:

```
$((function(){
   $(".draggable").mousedown(function () {
     $(this).mousemove(function(){
       $(this).css(/*alters the position of the div*/)
     });
   });
});
```

Note we're not using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) here, it's not for this case (and can't be used without a selector), you just want [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) directly (the [`.mousemove()`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) shortcut above uses [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) as well).